# [laravel 4 ]Redirect to another controller's method, where do i return the view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

it's about best practices here, my action route to a controller's method :

```
Route::get('/admin',array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PostController@create' ));
```

In PostController@create :

```
public function create(){
// Querying Model

 return Redirect::action('PictureController@index');
}
```

Because i need, to display the form to create a post, to get back all the pictures stored in the database (it's a file on the server, located by a 'url' field in pictures database table) so the admin can pick a picture for his post.

So at the end of the index method in PictureController i can return the view with all the data i need, so my question is :

Is there a way to separate the View response from the routing, like using a closure after i route to my several controller's action, or do i have to return the view in the last called method in my execution ?

Sorry for my english, hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filter like that :

```
Route::filter('name_of_filter', function($response, $type = 'html')
{
    //do your magic
});
```

in `filters.php` to make some treatments **after** all your work in controllers.

In your route, use `Route::get/('/admin', array('after' => 'name_of_filter', 'uses' => ...))` to apply this filter at the end of your request.

Comment: I use before filter all the time..Did not think to use 'after' filter for my problem, thanks you, very useful response.